# Linux Transparent Bridge with trunk VLAN

Tags: linux, bridge

I want to ask if this scenario is possible with Linux version 3.10 stock standard kernel to manage traffic in a transparent bridge mode.   I have 
a connection now between the LAN switch to the one port of a firewall which inturn is connected to the internet.  The LAN has 4 VLANs numbered(3,4,5,6) one four ports on the LAN switch and this is turn trunked (i hope that i am using the right terminology here) via one port of the switch to the firewall.

WAN ---- Linux Bridge ----- LAN

I want it insert an Linux box with 3 NIC, eth0, eth1 and eth3 where eth0 = LAN, eth1=WAN (where LAN and WAN are bridged br0) and eth3=management with ip to manage the box, where LAN, WAN and br0 are ip-less.  My Question are:

1) Can iptables see all the source and destination IP of all the VLANS?

2) Can I rate limit certain IPs from any of the 4 VLANS?

3) Can iptables filter by VLAN-id?

4) ebtables can mark packet of certain VLAN-id but can this mark inturn be managed by iptables?

Thanks for helping.

Regards,
Albert

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, because VLANs are handled in Linux with virtual interfaces eg `eth0.75` for VLAN id 75 on physical interface `eth0`.
2. I don't know, but I suspect so; given the above, any normal rate-limiting tools can be aware of the VLAN on which a packet arrived.
3. Yes, using the usual filters for input and output interface.
4. I don't know.

Comment: When you mentioned the virtual interfaces eg `eth0.75`, does that mean that the kernel automatically spin up an interface depending on the traffic passing through the bridge?

Comment: the kernel doesn't spin up any vlan interface automatically, you need to do it